# SQL UPDATE table row range with specific range of numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to use this script:

```
UPDATE tablename
SET tablecolumn = abs(checksum(NewId()) % 100 + 1)
WHERE ID between 162 and 166
```

What I am trying to do is update row 162 to 166 with 1-5 like

```
162 1
163 2
164 3
165 4
166 5
```

Comment: Just subtract 161?? What does `newid()` have to do with it?

Answer (score 4):

You can use ROW_NUMBER() to generate the series. However `SET column = ROW_NUMBER() ...` doesn't work. Instead you need to select the values in a an inline view (or CTE) and then update the values

```
UPDATE t
SET t.tablecolumn = t.tablecolumn_new
FROM (
      SELECT id, tablecolumn, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [id]) AS tablecolumn_new
      FROM tablename
     WHERE id between 162 and 166
      ) t;
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c4ef2/4)

Comment: getting a syntax error Line 7: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1:

Incorrect syntax near '.'.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone stop by this answear and just need a specific value instead...SQL credits to @Conrad Frix.

```
UPDATE t
SET t.tablecolumn = 100 --Changed this
FROM (
  SELECT id, tablecolumn --Changed this
  FROM tablename
 WHERE id between 162 and 166
  ) t;
```